# Codeigniter 4 ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::__construct(), 0 passed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Estoy intentando implementar arquitectura hexagonal en CI4, quiero hacer un metodo para guardar en la base de datos que accion se ejecutaron, para esto estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

app/PunkCore/Shared/Interfaces/Repository/UserActivityRepositoryInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace App\PunkCore\Shared\Interfaces\Repository;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

interface UserActivityRepositoryInterface
{
    public function saveActivity(
        string $method,
        bool $succeed,
        RequestInterface $request,
        ResponseInterface $response): void;
}
```

app/PunkCore/Shared/Infrastructure/Repository/UserActivityRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\PunkCore\Shared\Infrastructure\Repository;

use App\PunkCore\Shared\Interfaces\Repository\UserActivityRepositoryInterface;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

use App\Models\UserActivity;

class UserActivityRepository implements UserActivityRepositoryInterface
{

    public function saveActivity(
        string $method,
        bool $succeed,
        RequestInterface $request,
        ResponseInterface $response): void
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        UserActivity::create([
            'method' => $method,
            'succeed' => $succeed,
            'user' => $user->username,
            'ip' => $request->getIPAddress(),
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'request' => $request->getBody(),
            'response' => $response->getBody(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

app/PunkCore/Shared/Interfaces/Services/UserActivityServiceInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace App\PunkCore\Shared\Interfaces\Services;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

interface UserActivityServiceInterface
{
    public  function logUserActivity(
        string $method,
        bool $succeed,
        RequestInterface $request,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ): void;
}
```

app/PunkCore/Shared/Application/UserActivityService.php

```
<?php
namespace App\PunkCore\Shared\Application;

use  App\PunkCore\Shared\Interfaces\Services\UserActivityServiceInterface;
use  App\PunkCore\Shared\Interfaces\Repository\UserActivityRepositoryInterface;


use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

class UserActivityService implements UserActivityServiceInterface
{
    private $userActivityRepository;

    public function __construct(UserActivityRepositoryInterface $userActivityRepository)
    {
        $this->userActivityRepository = $userActivityRepository;
    }

    public function logUserActivity(
        string $method,
        bool $succeed,
        RequestInterface $request,
        ResponseInterface $response): void
    {
        $this->userActivityRepository->saveActivity($method, $succeed, $request, $response);
    }
}
```

app/Controllers/Admin/AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

use App\PunkCore\Shared\Interfaces\Repository\UserActivityRepositoryInterface;
use App\PunkCore\Shared\Infrastructure\Repository\UserActivityRepository;
use App\PunkCore\Shared\Interfaces\Services\UserActivityServiceInterface;
use App\PunkCore\Shared\Application\UserActivityService;

class AdminController extends BaseController
{
    use ResponseTrait;

    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $logger;
    protected $userActivityService;
    protected $userActivityRepository;

    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, UserActivityService $userActivityService, UserActivityRepositoryInterface $userActivityRepository)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->userActivityService = $userActivityService;
        $this->userActivityRepository = $userActivityRepository;
    }
    

    public function index()
    {
        if (!auth()->loggedIn()) {
            return view('admin/Auth/login');
        }
        
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {
        return view('admin/Auth/dashboard');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        echo'<pre>';print_r($this->request->getBody());echo'</pre>';
        $this->userActivityService->logUserActivity(__CLASS__ . '-' . __METHOD__, true, $this->request, $this->response);
        
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }

    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();
    }
}
```

Pero cuando quiero configurar el controlador me devuelve este error:
ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::__construct(), 0 passed in
mnt/d/html/punkframework/system/CodeIgniter.php on line 906 and exactly 4 expected

y no sé donde estoy fallando. Se que espera 4 parámetros y no se le esta pasando ninguno supuestamente, pero en el constructor del controlador le envió parámetros.